# WYSIWYG-able Footnote Plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Is there a WP plugin that allows user to edit in-page footnotes in WYSIWYG manner?

No weird syntax.

No HTML pane.

**Update:**

Perhaps I'm missing something, as I'm new to WP.

All footnote plugins that I saw use custom syntax. Example:

```
Blah blah blah ((my footnote)) blah
```

Other:

```
Blah blah blah [ref]my footnote[/ref]
```

I need plugin that will allow user to edit footnotes visually, like Word does.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? I know what a Footnote is and what WYSIWYG (mind the typo), but I don't get your question. I think you want to have this simple, but what are you talking about? Probably adding some sketch-picture or a little bit of description already helps to answer your question.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Where are you wanting to manage this foot note from, a custom plugin page? You may find the following info of use. http://www.keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: I want to edit footnotes on the same page where I write the text, of course.

Comment: And where is that exactly? Do you have a plugin that provides a facility for footnotes, are you writing a plugin or perhaps wanting help writing one that can do it(with wysiwyg)? Sorry it's not clear from your question..

Comment: @t31os: I just want to find a plugin. Don't want to code anything. (But if anyone can tell me where to look to code what I want, I'll probably do it.)

Comment: @t31os: regarding "where is that": wp-admin/post.php?post=<id>&action=edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the footnote plugins that I'm aware of, they don't provide the functionality you're looking for. It's normally expected that a user edits the footnotes content in the place where the footnote is edited in the current plugins.

But the list is pretty impressive. So probably you might want to look on your own: [Footnote Wordpress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=footnote&sort=).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked and did not found anything suitable -- that's why I'm asking a question here...

Comment: NetBlog plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/netblog/) seems to be closest to what I want. But still it is not WYSIWYG plugin, not suitable for casual Word-aware users.

Comment: It depends what you really need. I have casual users that prefer the more simple editor over WYSIWYG. And I have no idea right away how to offer that in a simple and easy way for footnotes.

Comment: Well, the kind of casual user that I'm setting up WP for is a grizzled professional Word user, who have no or little experience with almost any other software, especially blogging. Not the usual kind of "casual", I know.

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: Well, probably then don't expect too much from WYSIWYG for your users ;). Probably start w/o footnotes first and see which problems they already find in use. In the end they might just love any of the available solutions. Just that I have said it, many users actually have problems with WYSIWYG because it's complicated and full of issues.

Comment: But we *need* footnotes, that's the problem.

Comment: Well if nothing is available, try to find a hacker for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you mean, but if you use custom_fields to generate the footnotes, you can use [more fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) and use the WYSIWYG field for that usage.